# VBA: Doubleclick list box, identitfy values between commas and highlight corresponding identified values in another listbox

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, double-click

Image of userform,listbox

[image: Image of userform,listbox]

I'm struggling to know how to even ask this.

I have a UserForm, with listbox1 showing all the inputted data from the username. In the UserForm, I have a listbox2 which allows multiple selections, puts a comma between them and sends to a column in listbox1.

What I want to do now is the opposite of the above. Double-click row from listbox1, so that values are populated in the UserForm, including listbox2.

How can I amend the below form to do this?

Listbox1: Where I will double-click
Lisbox2: Homeroom (listbox with comma separated values)
Userform: Data in userform to be populated upon double-clicking a row

```vb
Private Sub ListBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

    txtSearch.Text = ListBox1.Column(1)
    
    If txtSearch.Text = ListBox1.Column(1) Then
    
        cmbGrade.Text = Me.ListBox1.Column(2)
        
        lstHomeroom = Me.ListBox1.Column(3)
              
        cmbSubjectCode.Text = Me.ListBox1.Column(4)
        
        cmbClassroom.Text = Me.ListBox1.Column(5)
        
        cmbNumberLessons.Text = Me.ListBox1.Column(7)
        
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not clear on your question (appreciate your 'not sure how to even ask this' comment!), can you clarify "so that values are populated in the UserForm, including listbox2" ... and it might help to include some screen-snip images of your UserForm and/or the ListBoxes (if you're not sure how to add images, see the *Images* section at the end of [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)).

Comment: Ah sorry, I've added an image with a little more information. Hope that clarifies it.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub ListBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Dim x As Integer, i As Integer, aName, y As Integer
    For x = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        ' Get selected item
        If ListBox1.Selected(x) Then
            ' Split item by comma
            aName = Split(Me.ListBox1.Column(2, x), ",")
            For i = 0 To UBound(aName)
                For y = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1
                    If Me.ListBox2.List(y) = aName(i) Then
                        ' Select an item of ListBox
                        Me.ListBox2.Selected(y) = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next y
            Next
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, listbox 2 already has the values in it. So instead of the double-click sending the data to listbox2, I was hoping to have those values highlighted in listbox2.

Comment: I have updated the code.